# Extend hierarchical PKI

Tags: public-key-infrastructure

The figure below shows four simple hierarchical PKIs. `A`, `R`, `H` and `N` are trust anchors of their PKI.

[image]

1. I am supposed to add exactly one certificate so that `T` trusts `G`, but not `D`. Furthermore `R` must not trust `P`. First I thought to let `C` certify `G`, but the solution proposes a certificate of `C` for `P`.

   If `C` certifies `P`, there exists a path from `R` to `P`. `P` becomes a child of `R`. Therefore `R` should trust `P`. But why is that not the case?
2. Another certificate is searched in order that `D` trusts `J` and `L`, but not `K`. Furthermore `N` must not trust `B`.

   When introducing a certificate from `D` to `B`, `D` will trust `J` and `L` but not `K`. The same moment trust from `N` to `J` and `L` arises (because there is a certification path). So how can this task be solved?

Comment: What PKI are we talking about? Can a cert carry more than one CA's signature?

Comment: See above. A certificate can only have one CA's signature.

Comment: What certificates does T trust initially?

Comment: T's trust anchor is R.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling this is really a graph theory puzzle. -- I kinda like those. -- But this is very different from a real live PKI implementation.

Anyway: here's what you could do in a real live PKI:

> 1. I am supposed to add exactly one certificate so that T trusts G, but not D.

Add G to T's list of trusted sites.

> Another certificate is searched in order that D trusts J and L, but not K

Add J and L (or just B) to T's list of trusted site.

Comment: +1 I guess the question is: does this homework problem have the concept of local OS trust stores?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not even certain what the question is here. `R` is a Root-CA. R has signed C. C has signed T. I understand that part. But who does T trust? And why? What's in T's trust store at the beginning of this? Just "R"? Both "C" and "R"? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand corretly, the "leaf" entities are end entity certificates, that trust only their own PKI trust anchor, but need to communicate with end entities of other PKIs *without* changing their trust anchor settings. Therefore, using only cross certification.

> I am supposed to add exactly one certificate so that T trusts G, but
>   not D. Furthermore R must not trust P.

In other words, T must consider G valid, but not D. R must also not consider P valid (that part is a little bit strange, but I understand that R trusts itself only).

> First I thought to let C
>   certify G, but the solution proposes a certificate of C for P.

If C certies G, it would generate a G´ (a different certificate  for the same entity). If C certifies P, it would generate a P' that still would be able to validate G. G, trusting C, would trust P'.

> If C certifies P, there exists a path from R to P. P becomes a child
>   of R. Therefore R should trust P. But why is that not the case?

P is not a child of C or R, but P'. Therefore, R does not trust P (neither G or C). R also will trust G, if you are wondering.

> Another certificate is searched in order that D trusts J and L, but
>   not K. Furthermore N must not trust B.
>
> When introducing a certificate from D to B, D will trust J and L but
>   not K. The same moment trust from N to J and L arises (because there
>   is a certification path). So how can this task be solved?

Since that looks like homework, I´ll let this one to you to solve, since with the expanation of the other item its seem easier to understand this one.